# Issue with sending email

Tags: android, email, smtp, connection, broadcastreceiver

Im attempting to send an email using this backgound email sender code ( https://github.com/kristijandraca/BackgroundMailLibrary ) in a wakeful broadcast receiver but while making some adjustments I learned that for some reason it could no longer send the emails when the phone was locked and on wifi. Here is the relevent code and the error report. I would appreciate any advice would be greatly appreciated.
In the error report I made All of the parts not about date bold to make it easier to read

**The main:**

```
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flight2);
public void start() {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 8000;
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(Flight2.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Flight2.this,0,alarmIntent,0);
        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void cancel() {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(Flight2.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=     PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Flight2.this,0,alarmIntent,0);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    public void startAt10(Calendar calendar) {







        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(Flight2.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Flight2.this,0,alarmIntent,0);







        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingintent;
        int interval = 1000 * 60 * 5;
        String Alarmset ="Alarmset";
        Toast.makeText(Flight2.this, Alarmset, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());


        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                interval, pendingIntent);
    }}

**Receiver:** 


public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);

        startWakefulService(context, service);
        Log.i("SimpleWakefulReceiver", "Running servicech1 "
                 );










    }



































}
```

**Service:**

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

    public AlarmService() {
        super("SimpleWakefulService");
        Log.i("SimpleWakefulReceiver", "Running servicechshould run "
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("SimpleWakefulReceiver", "Running servicech2 "
        );













            BackgroundMail bm = new BackgroundMail(AlarmService.this);
            bm.setGmailUserName();
            bm.setGmailPassword();
            bm.setMailTo(email);
            bm.setFormSubject("My Blackbox Notification Update");
            bm.setFormBody(Body);
            bm.send();
            Log.i("SimpleWakefulReceiver", "Running servicech3 "
            );












        AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
```

The sender:

```
public class GmailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator
{
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
private String user;
private String password;
private Session session;
private Multipart _multipart;

static
{
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
}

public GmailSender(String user, String password)
{
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    _multipart = new MimeMultipart();
}

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
{
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
}

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception
{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
    message.setSubject(subject);

    message.setText(body);
    message.setDataHandler(handler);
    if(_multipart.getCount() > 0)
        message.setContent(_multipart);
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
    else
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
    Transport.send(message);

}

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception
{
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource
{
    private byte[] data;
    private String type;

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type)
    {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data)
    {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setType(String type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getContentType()
    {
        if (type == null)
            return "application/octet-stream";
        else
            return type;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException
    {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException
    {
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");
    }
}
```

}

**Manifest Permissions & receiver declaration:**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Error Report:

```
07-27 20:31:19.690  22803-22952/holland.thomas.myblackbox2 W/System.err﹕ javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
07-27 20:31:19.690  22803-22952/holland.thomas.myblackbox2 W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
07-27 20:31:19.690  22803-22952/holland.thomas.myblackbox2 W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
07-27 20:31:19.690  22803-22952/holland.thomas.myblackbox2 W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
07-27 20:31:19.690  22803-22952/holland.thomas.myblackbox2 W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
07-27 20:31:19.700  22803-22952/holland.thomas.myblackbox2 W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
07-27 20:31:19.700  22803-22952/holland.thomas.myblackbox2 W/System.err﹕ at holland.thomas.myblackbox2.GmailSender.sendMail(GmailSender.java:76)
07-27 20:31:19.700  22803-22952/holland.thomas.myblackbox2 W/System.err﹕ at holland.thomas.myblackbox2.BackgroundMail$startSendingEmail.doInBackground(BackgroundMail.java:117)
07-27 20:31:19.700  22803-22952/holland.thomas.myblackbox2 W/System.err﹕ at holland.thomas.myblackbox2.BackgroundMail$startSendingEmail.doInBackground(BackgroundMail.java:90)
07-27 20:31:19.700  22803-22952/holland.thomas.myblackbox2 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-27 20:31:19.700  22803-22952/holland.thomas.myblackbox2 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-27 20:31:19.710  22803-22952/holland.thomas.myblackbox2 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-27 20:31:19.710  22803-22952/holland.thomas.myblackbox2 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-27 20:31:19.710  22803-22952/holland.thomas.myblackbox2 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
```

Comment: I removed a middle part of the error code because stackoverflow thought it was spam and would not let me post it all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with its working for me:

```
 package com.javamail;

 import java.util.Properties;
 import javax.activation.DataHandler;
 import javax.activation.DataSource;
 import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
 import javax.mail.BodyPart;
 import javax.mail.Message;
 import javax.mail.Multipart;
 import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
 import javax.mail.Session;
 import javax.mail.Transport;
 import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
 import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
 import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
 import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.util.Log;


 public class Mail 
 { 
     MimeMessage message;
     private Multipart _multipart; 
     private String to_mail;
     private String subject;
     private String mailDescription;

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception
{ 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
} 

public Mail()
{ 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 
} 

public boolean send() throws Exception
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("orginalsenderemailaddress@gmail.com",
                    "password");
        }
    });

    session.setDebug(true);


    final Transport transport = session.getTransport();
    InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(getToMail());
    message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setSender(addressFrom);
    message.setSubject(getSubject());
    message.setContent(getMailDescription(), "text/plain");
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressFrom);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                if (_multipart!=null) {
                     message.setContent(_multipart);
                }
                transport.connect();
                Transport.send(message);
                transport.close();
                Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@", "mail sent @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }.execute();

    return false;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public String getMailDescription() {
    return mailDescription;
}

public void setMailDescription(String mailDescription) {
    this.mailDescription = mailDescription;
}

public String getToMail() {
    return to_mail;
}

public void setToMail(String to_mail) {
    this.to_mail = to_mail;
} 


}
```

If network is available call this where ever you want:

```
 if(new NetworkConnection(this).isConnectionAvailable())
 {
            sendEmail();
 }
```

Here is sender :

```
 private void sendEmail() {
    Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.setToMail("to mail address");
        mail.setSubject("Subject");
        mail.setMailDescription("Description");
        mail.addAttachment("file path")// if attachment is there
        try {
            mail.send();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v(Email_Tag, ""+e);
        }


}
```

Comment: so far everything is compatible except for  import com.utils.AppConstants; and NetworkConnection. did you get them from another library? for network connection the error is that it cannot resolve it.

Comment: No , its part of my project.I just edited my code com.utils.AppConstants is my import remove it in yours. and NetworkConnection Class is to check internet availability if internet is available then call sendEmail() else do as you required. if satisfied Up vote it.

Comment: I tryed it and it gave me the same error with your code. It only doesnt work when the phone is on wifi and the screen is locked.